# Excel: which function to use for a conditional copy of a bold cell?

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I have a big data set that I want to edit.

Therefore I need to copy the value of a cell of the column before the designated cell: if it is a value that is bold. If the value in the column before is not bold, than the function needs to check the value of the column before the designated cell and one row above. If this one is bold than take this value, if not, go check the value one row above, etc.

In the picture added I made a simple example of my situation now and how it needs to be.

Obviously if the dataset was as small as in the picture it would be doable by hand. But this isn't an option with a big dataset.

Below is an example of the situation now and the outcome wanted.

[image]

Comment: You need vba; there is no function that identifies a bold cell reliably.

Comment: Also, in general it is a really really bad idea to embed infomrmation in the formating.

Answer (score 2):

- First choice would be to have a list of classes in a table, and use that to determine which value to copy to column B.
- Second choice would be a VBA routine to identify the bold formatting
- Third choice without VBA (but referring to an XLM4 macro):

Under Formulas --> Define Name

```
Bold  Refers to:  =GET.CELL(20,OFFSET(INDIRECT("RC",FALSE),0,-1))
```

This will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on the boldness of the first letter in the cell one column to the left of where you have entered the named formula `Bold`

```
B4:  =IF(A4="","",IF(Bold,A4,B3))
```

and fill down.

A major problem with using `Bold` quality to detect is that it will not update if the `Bold` quality is changed unless a calculation event is also triggered.  And changing the font will not do that.

That is why a list of Classes might be a better approach.

Assume you have a named range someplace called `Classes`

Then you could use this formula:

```
B4:  =IF(COUNTIF(Classes,A4),A4,B3)
```

As you can see, they both work statically, but note that in formatting the cells, the `Bold` quality disappeared. Since that formula had been entered before the formatting was applied, nothing changed.  So the "Table" column returns the correct result; the "Bold" column is also returning the desired result, but will not after the next calculation event.

[image]